# __file__ and os.path module not playing nicely?

Tags: python, module, path

```
import os
print __file__
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir('/tmp')
print __file__  # unchanged, of course
print os.path.dirname(__file__)  # now broken
```

I have this issue above where `dirname(__file__)` can no longer be relied upon after `os.chdir` has been used in the script, after module loader has set `__file__`.

What is the usual mechanism for working around this, assuming you may not know where/when/how `os.chdir` may have been called previously?

**edit:** i hope this second example can better clarify my issue

```
import os
old_dir = os.getcwd()
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
os.chdir('/tmp')
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
os.chdir(old_dir)
```

the output is like this :

```
wim@wim-acer:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.1+
wim@wim-acer:~$ pwd
/home/wim
wim@wim-acer:~$ python /home/wim/spam.py
/home/wim/spam.py
/home/wim/spam.py
wim@wim-acer:~$ python ./spam.py
/home/wim/spam.py
/tmp/spam.py
```

Comment: Can't reproduce on Windows 7, Python 2.6.2. Does the directory switched to matter, or does any directory do this? Must the file be imported, or can it be run stand-alone? What Python version are you using? How exactly is it "broken" the second time (what isn't as expected)?

Comment: "What is the usual mechanism for working around this"? What?  Why do you what the absolute path to `__file__`?  Why are you waiting until after you do "not know where/when/how os.chdir may have been called previously" to get the absolute path?

Comment: sorry , the reason is for use in a debug helper function.  i use inspect module to get a bunch of other information , so that instead of littering code with `'print i'`, for example, i could use `dbgp('i')` and get a differently coloured line of output like `/abs/path/to_file.py:line_number i = repr(i)`

Comment: @Cameron , i apologize i wasn't very clear in my first example.  i have answered your questions in the second edit.

Comment: So is your ultimate goal a nicer/better debug output?

Comment: @Keith yes, some printouts that is easy to turn on/off by commenting a single line, traceable to the exact source it is being printed from, and visually distinguished from other normal print statements in a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__file__` must exist in `sys.path` somewhere.

```
for dirname in sys.path:
   if os.path.exists( os.path.join(dirname,__file__) ):
       # The directory name for `__file__` was dirname
```

Comment: could not the same filename in `__file__` exist in `sys.path` multiple times?

Comment: @wim: Yes.  It could.  So?  Python searches sys.path in order when it loads.  You're searching in the same order.

Comment: this is mostly correct.  however, there is a special case where `__file__` was an absolute path, and `os.path.exists(dirname,__file__)` returns True because `dirname`, from `sys.path[0]`, was `''` (the empty string).

Answer (score 1):

The last example has a relative path element in the `__file__` name (`./xxx.py`). When `abspath` is called with that it is expanded to the current directory.

If you put this code in a module you won't have that issue.